# How to get column 0 text from a ttk.Treeview's item

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, tk-toolkit, ttk

`Treeview.item` just gets the other columns from `1` on. How can I get `c#0` column value?

```
tree.insert("", 0, text="this is what I want to get", values=record)
```

Comment: Please elaborate more we need more information in order to be able to help you.

Comment: Explain in detail. And a bit of code always helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a reference to the item, you can use the `item` method of the tree to get the attributes of the item. For example, a binding might look like this:

```
def print_text(self, event):
    item = event.widget.identify("item", event.x, event.y)
    text = event.widget.item(item, "text")
    print "the text is '%s'" % text
...
tree.bind("<1>", self.print_text)
```